# how to get en id of clicked element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an id as a string of a div that was clicked. is it possible to do?

## HTML

```
<div id="test">
    <div class='button' id="a" ><p>Click 1</p></div>
    <div class='button' id="b" ><p>Click 2</p></div>
    <div class='button' id="c" ><p>Click 3</p></div>
    <div class='button' id="d" ><p>Click 4</p></div>
</div>
```

I can do something like this:

```
  $("#a").click(function() {
      /* do some action with this div */
  });
```

But I want to detect the id of just clicked div, because I will have a lot of divs like this, and it doesn't make sense to rewrite the same code over and over again.

Comment: Although your HTML is fine, I think I'd choose another class name for your divs: IMO, 'button' can be confusing.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to have a <p> tag inside your divs; just put the text directly inside the div. As a general rule, when you have a box inside a box (think of tags as boxes) you can probably simplify the HTML by removing the inner box and apply the css of the inner box to the outter box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#a").click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
});
```

If you need to set `click` event for all `.button` elements, here is the short way:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    var id = this.id;  // or e.target.id;
});
```

Comment: `this.id` would also work in the second example (in this case where no bubbling would have occurred `this` and `e.target` will be the same).

Comment: @nnnnnn Absolutely true. I simply added another way of getting `id`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.button").click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

will get you the id, But if you want to access the div you can use

```
$(this).parent('div')
```

this will only return if the immediate parent is a div, if want to find up you can use

```
$(this).parents('div')
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct. jQuery object doesn't have `id` property.

Comment: $(this).id will always be undefined. this.id is what you want. $(this).prop("id") will work but is slow.